# Delete files after x number of days and ignore one subfolder

Tags: powershell

While using another powershell script that I found online works it is deleting the directories instead of the files inside of the directories. The whole idea is to look in certain folders while ignoring one folder and delete files older than 365 days while leaving the subfolders. Here is the script that I have tried to modify:

```
# Variables 
$dump_path = "C:\DoceServe"    # set folder path this would be changed to a network drive
$Ignore_Path = "C:\DoceServe\System" # I want to ignore the system folder on the network drive
$max_days = "-365"    # set min age of files
$curr_date = Get-Date    # get the current date
$del_date = $curr_date.AddDays($max_days)   # determine how far back we go based on current date
$includefiles = "*.txt, *.bak, *.csv, *.prn, *.PDF, *.S@#"  # determine what to include in the delete
$excludefiles = "DoceServe Info* , DoceServe Log*"   # Determine what to exclude from the delete  -Exclude $exclude

# delete the files
Get-ChildItem $dump_path -Exclude $excludefiles -Include $includedfiles  | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $del_date } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am new with using powershell and some of it is kind of confusing.

Comment: What version of powershell?

Comment: What exact issues are you having. By quick glance it looks like -include and -exclude need to be string arrays, so you would want to fix that. I might also add `-and $_.FullName -notmatch $Ignore_Path` in your `where-object` item.

Answer (score 0):

- `$dump_path`, `$Ignore_Path` need to have trailing `\*`
- `$includefiles`, `$excludefiles` need to be arrays.
- the `-Recurse` parameter has to be on the Get-ChildItem definitely not on the Remove-Item

This script works here (with diffferent paramter values)

```
## Q:\Test\2018\05\11\SF_911512.ps1
$dump_path =   "C:\DoceServe\*"
$Ignore_Path = "C:\DoceServe\System\*"

$max_days = -365
$del_date = (Get-Date).AddDays($max_days)

$includefiles = @("*.txt","*.bak","*.csv","*.prn","*.PDF","*.S@#")
$excludefiles = @("DoceServe Info*","DoceServe Log*")

# delete the files
Get-ChildItem $dump_path -Inc $includefiles -Excl $excludefiles -Recurse |
  Where-Object { !($_.PSIsContainer) -and
                   $_.LastWriteTime -lt $del_date -and
                   $_.Directory -notlike $Ignore_Path } |
    Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
```

For brevity paramter names can be shortened as long they are uniquely identifiable